# function PDO query and multidimansional array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to get a multidimensional array returned from a function.

I want to have the column names as first level and data as second level.

```
array[columnName][data]
```

I can `var_dump()` the function and get the correct output, but I can't `echo()` the output.

```
<?php

function fetch_columname($schema,$tablename)
{
    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname='dbname', 'user', 'pass'");
        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM    `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=:schema AND `TABLE_NAME`=:tablename");
        $query->bindParam(":schema", $schema);
        $query->bindParam(":tablename", $tablename);
        $query->execute();

        $result = array();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
    return $result;
}
$columname = array();
$columname = fetch_columname('new_site','users');
$count = count($columname);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    echo $columname[$i];
}
```

Comment: "I hope somebody can see what i'm doing wrong": You don't indent your code.

Comment: without mentioning the obvious forgotten double-quote in your dsn string. I say obvious because just looking at code coloring in your question, all this red shouldn't be there. Don't you use some IDE? Heard about netbeans or phpstorm?

Comment: i editet the "wrong's", was a faulty delete of the pass and username i was using for security reasons :)

Comment: So what is actually the problem you are having?  Not sure what you are asking here. Your function would return a two-dimensional array as written, though I am honestly not sure why you want a two-dimensional array considering you are only returning a single field in your query.  I would simply change `$result[] = $row` to `$result[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME']` and call it a day. Everything from that point should work just fine.

Comment: the echo part is the problem:)
and this is mine first step in building a multidimansional array :)
I cant echo $columname[$i];
what works is:
$columname = fetch_columname('new_site','users');
var_dump($columname);

Comment: thnx mike brant $result[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'] whas the solution :)

Comment: I apologize for my prior condescending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529853/mike-brant) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378317/function-pdo-query-and-multidimansional-array#comment46937479_29378317):

> Your function would return a two-dimensional array as written, though I am honestly not sure why you want a two-dimensional array considering you are only returning a single field in your query. I would simply change `$result[] = $row` to `$result[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME']` and call it a day.